# How to start bach proces from anonymouse window

Tags: apex, batch, class, anonymous

I Have the following batch process. How do I test this from an anonymous window?

```
global class Batchtest implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Id <variable name>= Database.executeBatch(new <Class name>(), batch size);
```

**Example code**

```
Id batchJobId =  Database.executebatch(new Batchtest() , 200);
```

Where 200 is your scope.Scope is not mandatory. If you do not pass scope, default is 200 and maximum you can set is 2000.

**Note:**
batchJobId will contain the job Id of the batch.